# Is the direct sum preserved under isomorphism

Tags: modules, exact-sequence, free-modules, group-rings, module-isomorphism

I have edited this based on discussions in the comments:

This really is more of a sanity check and I couldn't seem to find an answer to anything similar anywhere, so apologies if this has already been asked in some form or another.

I have three $R$-submodules $A,B,C$ of an $R$-module $M$ such that $M\cong A\oplus B\oplus C$. I was thinking of $R$ being an integral group ring but I am also curious if this is true for any ring (commutative or non-commutative). I know that $A,B,C$ are free as $R$-mods.

Now suppose further that we have another three $R$-modules $A^\prime,\,B^\prime,C^\prime$. We have isomorphisms $A\cong A^\prime,\,B\cong B^\prime,\,C\cong C^\prime$. From discussions below with Qiaochu Yuan, I am now happy to say that this means $M\cong A^\prime\oplus B^\prime\oplus C^\prime$ also.

My question now is how this affects the bases. If $\mathcal{B}_A,\,\mathcal{B}_B,\,\mathcal{B}_C$ are the bases for $A,\,B,\,C$, respectively, then clearly their union form a basis for $A\oplus B\oplus C$. If $\mathcal{B}_{A^\prime},\,\mathcal{B}_{B^\prime},\,\mathcal{B}_{C^\prime}$ are bases for $A^\prime,\,B^\prime,\,C^\prime$, respectively, does this mean that $\mathcal{B}_{A^\prime}\cup\mathcal{B}_{B^\prime}\cup\mathcal{B}_{C^\prime}$ is a basis for $A^\prime\oplus B^\prime\oplus C^\prime$?

My issue I think is that we seem to be getting LI for free. So obviously the elements in $\mathcal{B}_{A^\prime}$ are LI, as are the elements in $\mathcal{B}_{B^\prime}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{C^\prime}$, but we are now also getting that $\mathcal{B}_{A^\prime}\cup\mathcal{B}_{B^\prime}\cup\mathcal{C}_{C^\prime}$  is a LI set, despite not showing it.

Comment: Yes, the point of isomorphisms is precisely to make statements like this true.  There is no need to talk about exact sequences, just write down the isomorphism directly by taking the direct sum of the given isomorphisms between the components.

Comment: Hi @QiaochuYuan, thanks for the reply. So could I add to this? Suppose $\mathcal{B}_A$, $\mathcal{B}_B$ and $\mathcal{B}_C$ are bases for $A,\,B,\,C$, respectively (so, in particular, $\mathcal{B}_A\cup\mathcal{B}_B\cup\mathcal{B}_C$ is a basis for $M$). If $\mathcal{B}_{A^\prime}$, $\mathcal{B}_{B^\prime}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{C^\prime}$ are bases for $A^\prime,B^\prime,C^\prime$, does this mean that $\mathcal{B}_{A^\prime}\cup\mathcal{B}_{B^\prime}\cup\mathcal{B}_{C^\prime}$ is also a basis for $M$? I was thinking of these being $\mathbb{Z}$-bases (hence considering $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-mods.

Comment: No; once we're talking about bases we're no longer working up to isomorphism. A basis must in particular be a subset, so now strictly speaking we need to say that this basis transports along the isomorphism $A' \oplus B' \oplus C' \cong A \oplus B \oplus C$ to a basis of $M$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Right, so I think there is partly where my confusion lies. I have 3 subsets and I've used them to generate $A, B, C$. I've also shown $A\cap(B+C)$ etc. are trivial, so we can form a direct sum. I've also got another 3 subsets and used these to form $A^\prime, B^\prime C^\prime$, but showing these form a direct sum is tricky since they don't look nearly so nice. But I have shown $A\cong A^\prime$ etc. So is this sufficient?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking about direct sums or about bases or about generating sets? Those are three different things.

Comment: So what I mean is, I have six generating sets contained in $M$, one for each of $A, A^\prime, B, B^\prime, C, C^\prime$ and I have shown all are LI (so I have 6 bases). Since I have shown $M\cong A\oplus B\oplus C$ I have a basis $\mathcal{B}_A\cup\mathcal{B}_B\cup\mathcal{B}_C$ for M by taking the union of these LI spanning sets. I also have $A\cong A^\prime, B\cong B^\prime, C\cong C^\prime$, and so by the above $M\cong A^\prime\oplus B^\prime\oplus C^\prime$. Does this mean $\mathcal{B}_{A^\prime}\cup\mathcal{B}_{B^\prime}\cup\mathcal{B}_{C^\prime}$ is also a basis for $M$?

Comment: No, as I already mentioned; the issue is that it's no longer a subset of $M$. It transports along the isomorphism $M \cong A' \oplus B' \oplus C'$ to a subset of $M$ and this transported subset is a basis.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sorry if I wasn't clear, but what if the bases are all subsets of $M$? So, in other words, $\mathcal{B}_A, \mathcal{B}_{A^\prime}$ etc. are all made up of elements of $M$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sorry to add to this, but I suppose what I am actually trying to get at (and would be sufficient for me) is whether $\mathcal{B}_{A^\prime}\cup \mathcal{B}_{B^\prime}\cup\mathcal{B}_{C^\prime}$ is a basis for $A^\prime\oplus B^\prime\oplus C^\prime$.

Comment: Yes, there's no issue with that, it's exactly the same as the argument for $A \oplus B \oplus C$. (Although since I was already being pretty pedantic before it's worth noting that I am implicitly ignoring the difference between internal and external direct sums here.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, so that is what I was thinking, but I suppose I was concerned about the LI of all three. This is where my confusion lies. If $\mathcal{B}_{A^\prime},\mathcal{B}_{B^\prime},\mathcal{B}_{C^\prime}$ are all $\mathbb{Z}$-bases for $A^\prime,B^\prime,C^\prime$, then clearly $\mathcal{B}_{A^\prime}$ is LI over $A^\prime$ etc. If $\mathcal{B}_{A^\prime}\cup\mathcal{B}_{B^\prime}\cup\mathcal{B}_{C^\prime}$ a basis of the direct sum then this is obviously a LI set, but it feels too good to be true For example, in principle, what if $\mathcal{B}_{A^\prime}=\mathcal{B}_{B^\prime}$?

Comment: Okay, at this point we need to make some maps explicit that I was hoping to leave implicit, I can write up a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

Re: your questions in the comments, the issue here is that to be fully precise about what's going on we need to name some of the maps involved which have not been named up to this point. So, let $A', B', C'$ be free modules, and let $\phi : M \cong A' \oplus B' \oplus C'$ be an isomorphism (where the direct sum here is an external direct sum, to be totally clear). Let

$$i_{A'}, i_{B'}, i_{C'} : A', B', C' \to A' \oplus B' \oplus C'$$

be the inclusion map of each direct summand. Finally let $G_{A'} \subset A', G_{B'} \subset B', G_{C'} \subset C'$ be bases. Then the completely precise claim is that

> **Claim 1:** $i_{A'}(G_{A'}) \cup i_{B'}(G_{B'}) \cup i_{C'}(G_{C'})$ is a basis of $A' \oplus B' \oplus C'$ (and in particular this union is always disjoint), and

> **Claim 2:** $\phi^{-1}(i_{A'}(G_{A'}) \cup i_{B'}(G_{B'}) \cup i_{C'}(G_{C'}))$ is a basis of $M$.

It's a fairly common abuse of notation to leave these maps implicit because naming them and writing them out is annoying and clutters things up most of the time, but in this case we need to to be totally clear about what's going on. Note that it can even be the case that, say, $A' = B' = C'$ and $G_{A'} = G_{B'} = G_{C'}$ and the above still holds, because the inclusion maps into the direct sum are different. So there's no issue with some of them being equal; *after* the inclusion maps are applied they are necessarily disjoint.

With $A, B, C$ you already specified they were submodules so the direct sum is internal and in this case it's even more common to avoid naming the inclusion maps because $G_{A'} \cup G_{B'} \cup G_{C'}$ is already a subset of $M$ on the nose. This is in the same way that we typically don't bother naming any of the inclusion maps $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ and are just applying them implicitly all the time.

Re: your original questions, here are some general facts you can try to prove as an exercise.

> **Claim 3:** If $M, N$ are two free modules, $\phi : M \cong N$ is an isomorphism, and $G \subset M$ is a basis of $M$, then $\phi(G)$ is a basis of $N$.

> **Claim 4:** If $M, N$ are two modules, $M', N'$ are two other modules, and $\phi_M : M \cong M'$ and $\phi_N : N \cong N'$ are isomorphisms with inverses $\phi_M^{-1}, \phi_N^{-1}$, then

> $$\phi_M \oplus \phi_N : M \oplus N \ni m \oplus n \mapsto \phi_M(m) \oplus \phi_N(n) \in M' \oplus N'$$

> is an isomorphism with inverse $\phi_M^{-1} \oplus \phi_N^{-1}$. (The same is true for any number of direct summands, including infinitely many direct summands; for the case of finitely many direct summands it follows from this binary case by induction.)

Claim 4 follows directly from the fact that taking direct sums is a [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor); any functor whatsoever sends isomorphisms to isomorphisms.

Comment: Many thanks for this. It is much clearer now and I will try proving as an exercise. This really is very much appreciated. As one final comment, and more so I know I am not overthinking anything, $A^\prime, B^\prime, C^\prime$ are also submodules, so the direct sum is internal in this case also. I presume this doesn't change anything?

Comment: Well, submodules of what? If you already have some $M'$ in mind that they're submodules of such that $M'$ is an internal direct sum then that's one thing. Otherwise strictly speaking you are talking about an external direct sum, which is an internal direct sum not of $A', B', C'$ but of $i_{A'}(A'), i_{B'}(B'), i_{C'}(C')$. This is very pedantic and again it's common to ignore the difference between these two things but very strictly speaking they're not precisely the same.

Comment: Submodules of $M$. So $A,A^\prime,...$ are all submodules of $M$. I have shown $M\cong A\oplus B\oplus C$ and $A\cong A^\prime$...so $M\cong A^\prime\oplus B^\prime\oplus C^\prime$.  I suppose nothing you said above about external direct sums changes here for the internal direct sums?

Comment: So, again, at the level of pedantic we've been so far, it is not true that $A', B', C'$ are submodules of $M$ on the nose, they are just *isomorphic to* submodules of $M$. There are again maps here that have not been named that need to be named to be clear about what's going on. If we name the isomorphisms $\phi_A : A \cong A'$ etc. then the correct statement is that $\phi_A^{-1}(A')$, etc. are submodules of $M$ (namely the submodules $A, B, C$).

Comment: Basically the reason we have to do this kind of thing is that "submodule" is not a good category-theoretic concept, because it requires something to be a subset on the nose (same with "basis"). The good category-theoretic concept is the notion of a subobject which just requires a monomorphism that need not be a subset inclusion: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject#as_classes_of_monomorphisms

Comment: No, they are submodules. They are the $\mathbb{Z}$-span of elements in $M$, so they form a submodule of $M$.

Comment: Well, that's a different situation then. All you previously said was that they were isomorphic to submodules! Maybe you should just write down exactly what all these modules are in the situation you have in mind to be clearer.

Comment: Basically, what I'd like is to show $A^\prime\oplus B^\prime\oplus C^\prime\cong M$ so that I can work with the basis of the LHS since that is nicer than the basis of $A\oplus B\oplus C$. Now I can show A\cap(B+C)={0} and so on, so I do have an honest direct sum $A\oplus B\oplus C$ iso to $M$. I also have $A\cong A^\prime$ and so on, so that means $A^\prime\oplus B^\prime\oplus C^\prime\cong M$. What I was originally wondering was whether that meant I could then use the basis of $A^\prime\oplus B^\prime\oplus C^\prime$.

Comment: I did mention that I took 3 more subsets to generate $A^\prime$ etc. but yes I agree I was far from clear.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you mean because now you haven't said anything about $A', B', C'$ being submodules of $M$ on the nose. Are you saying that $A, B, C$ are three submodules of $M$ such that $M$ is their internal direct sum, and also $A', B', C'$ are three *other* submodules of $M$, which happen to be abstractly isomorphic to $A, B, C$ as modules?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm saying. I have edited the question to hopefully make this clearer.

Comment: Okay, then I'm glad we were very pedantic because the pedantry really matters now. In this situation we need to be very specific: $M$ is isomorphic to the *external* direct sum of $A', B', C'$, but you seem to want $M$ to be the *internal* direct sum of $A', B', C'$, and this simply need not be true in general. For example we might have $A' = B' = C'$ or similar. Now we really need to be specific about all the maps we have flying around because there are two *different* ways to map $A', B', C'$ into $M$, the natural inclusions and one the inclusions you get after applying the isomorphisms.

Comment: Right, this is just where I feared things would be. It seemed that things were too good to be true. You're right, I do need the internal direct sum (I will need to look more into the differences between internal and external direct sums) and, as you say $A^\prime=B^\prime=C^\prime$ is a possibility. Indeed, the reason I ended up here was specifically because I did not want to physically show their intersections were trivial and could think of no other way to do this.